# Getting elements in getelementsbyclassname not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodelist, htmlcollection

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar-holder");
console.log(list);// html collection of length 2
console.log(list[0]);// undefined
```

Here I have run the following code and I have used the comments to `console.log()` the results.

While the elements with that class name are being rendered asynchronously, I do not believe that this is the problem as the first `console.log()` renders the expected result. The second one does not.

Comment: You're seeing a live reference of your list (ie: so you're seeing its contents at the time of viewing it), not its contents for when it was logged.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Array.from(list)` to convert the HTML element to array before you can iterate over it. That's so because HTML element are array-like but not pure arrays.